# Add map values in a loop

Tags: java, android, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to put some values in a loop for in java, but I only can get one value when finish the loop. I've tried to find something but I can't find anything...

```
 List<Double> prices = new ArrayList<>();
 Map<Boolean, Double> map = new HashMap<Boolean, Double>();

 for (Rewards rewardsPrice : Preferences.getRewards()) {
     map.put(rewardsPrice.isPreference(), rewardsPrice.getCredit()); // when finish the loop I only have 1 value, when prices have a lot of more
 }

 Set<Boolean> keys = map.keySet(); // The set of keys in the map.
 Iterator<Boolean> keyIter = keys.iterator();

 while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
      Boolean key = keyIter.next();
      Double value = map.get(key);
      map.put(key, value);
 }
```

Comment: What is the size of `Preferences.getRewards()`?

Comment: depends, rigth now have 6 values, but could be more in the future

Comment: Well if your key is a boolean  you can only have a max of 2 values. Do you need  `Map<Boolean, List<Double>>`?

Comment: The key of your map is Boolean, which means it can hold only true or false - how do you expect it to hold more than 2 values?

Comment: it seems the rewardsPrice.isPreference() always return the same boolean...

Comment: boolean type of key is issue here, may be always get same boolean value, and max you can have only 2 keys like "true" or "false"

Answer (score 1):

Here Key is of type Boolean,since Boolean can have only 2 values TRUE, FALSE and NULL(being an object) map can have max 3 entries at any given time. It is highly possible that all 6 values are being put against a single key value(TRUE/FALSE/NULL). Map always maintains a single value against a key.

```
Map<Boolean, Double> map = new HashMap<Boolean, Double>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Double> prices = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Rewards> map = new HashMap<String, Rewards>();

for (Rewards rewardsPrice : Preferences.getRewards()) {
    if (rewardsPrice.isPreference()) {
        prices.add(rewardsPrice.getCredit());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some textual information to your answer, please. Otherwise it cannot be considered a good answer.

Comment: Thank you for edit, new to StackOverflow(in Ans), not very good with words, well i will keep in mind for next time, Thanks.

Comment: OK, please keep in mind that words are mandatory in a question-answer community.